# Each form item as new row in mySql table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

We have a form where the user may add unlimited items.. Like this:

```
product[]
amount[]
qty[]
total[]

product[]
amount[]
qty[]
total[]

product[]
amount[]
qty[]
total[]
```

When the form is submitted, we need to create one table row for each item in our mysql database.

```
ID     Qty     Amount     Total
1      2       100        200
2      1       20         20
3      2       50         100
```

We use ajax to submit the form, and PHP to create the order in our database... but how to make a new table row for each item?

I'm lost. Need your help :)

Comment: So `product[0]` is then `1` and `total[0]` is `200`?

Comment: you write an `insert` query... we don't write code for you. you write the code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I feel like @Virik is using the same IDs/names for each for field, which is causing the issue.

Comment: @Virik can you show us what the form fields look like in html? Please include an example that include a couple added form fields from the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cnt=count($product);
$product=array_map('intval',$product);//$_REQUEST['product'];
$amount=array_map('intval',$amount);
$qty=array_map('intval',$qty);
$total=array_map('intval',$total);
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
    $rows[]="({$product[$i]},{$qty[$i]},{$amount[$i]},{$total[$i]})";
}
print "INSERT INTO tablename (ID ,Qty ,Amount ,Total) VALUES ".implode(', ',$rows);
```

The rest is one you...

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, and for pointing me in the right direction. This is what I needed.

Comment: How come INSERT fails when changing from intval to strval?

$name = array_map('strval', $_POST['name']);

Comment: Never mind, just needed to wrap " around the string.